# How to drop name from df.columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to know how to remove the `name` from the `df.columns` attribute:

Let's say I have the following dataframe with df.columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]})
df

    a   b
0   1   4
1   2   5
2   3   6

df.columns

Index(['a', 'b'], dtype='object')
```

And then if I add a name to the columns attribute then I get the dataframe:

```
df.columns.name = 'test'
df.columns

Index(['a', 'b'], dtype='object', name='test')

df

test    a   b
   0    1   4
   1    2   5
   2    3   6
```

Is there a way to drop the name `test` that appears above the index?

Comment: Seems like a strange problem, why would you add the name attribute if you don't want it there? Or are you just wanting to remove it for displaying purposes, but retain the attribute?

Comment: @sacul I came upon that issue with pivot_table, but wanted to leave that out of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete the attribute via `del`:

```
df.columns.name = 'test'
print(df.columns)
# Index(['a', 'b'], dtype='object', name='test')

del df.columns.name
print(df.columns)
# Index(['a', 'b'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can using `rename_axis`

```
df.rename_axis(None,axis=1)
Out[68]: 
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

Answer (score 1):

`df.columns.name=None`
Would be my solutions

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why you would name the attribute to then drop its name, but you can use the same code used to name it:

`df.columns.name=None`

Comment: It was probably for demonstration - and this is the same answer that @HowdyDude provided before you. Additional answers should only be added if they bring something new or different to the question.

Comment: As already commented- Either this post should be updated to add new information or remove since the answer is the same as what @HowdyDude provided.